# How to create rails log file by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logfiles

I am very new to Rails and I really don't like rails default behaviour that it saves all logs in a single log file. Is that possible to archive log file separated by date like development.06-13-2014.log, development.06-14.2014, etc..?

Sorry if I had asked some silly question but I would like to know if there is any way to maintain log file such way.. I appreciate for well explained answers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `logrotate` - this is a program which runs in the background, and will truncate and rename files on a scheduled basis (eg daily).  You won't make any changes to rails itself.  Just google `logrotate <your OS>`

Comment: Sorry to ask you here by comment.. can u please help me in this http://goo.gl/dGCkgx